# Qt endl looks great from linux telnet, wrong from windows telnet

Tags: qt, qstring, qtcpsocket, qtnetwork, qtcore

I am building a telnet server app in Qt, and when I connect from a linux telnet client output looks great.  For example, sending "A" << endl << "B" << endl << "C" to my console looks like:

```
A
B
C
```

Now when I connect from a Windows telnet client I see

```
A
 B
  C
```

obviously Qt's endl is sending only '\n'.  Is there a SIMPLE solution to this?  If I replace endl with "\r\n" do I mess up linux clients now?  Do I have to force a flush too?

Here is actual code I am using to send to my telnet client:

```
QString block;
QTextStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out << "Valid commands are: " << endl
    << "  help         Print this list" << endl
    << "  version      Print this version" << endl
    << "  clientcount  Show the number of active telnet clients" << endl
    << "  logrotate    Rotate the event log file" << endl
    << "  shutdown     Initiate shutdown secast" << endl
    << "  quit         Disconnect your telnet session" << endl
    << "  stop         Shutdown secast" << endl;
tcpSocketPtr->write(block.toUtf8());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply drop the `QTextStream` and write the `QString` directly in here:

```
QString block = QString("Valid commands are: \n")
            + "  help         Print this list\n"
            + "  version      Print this version\n"
            + "  clientcount  Show the number of active telnet clients\n"
            + "  logrotate    Rotate the event log file\n"
            + "  shutdown     Initiate shutdown secast\n"
            + "  quit         Disconnect your telnet session\n"
            + "  stop         Shutdown secast\n";

tcpSocketPtr->write(block.toUtf8());
```

Based on your comment though, you seem to use some old DOS client (on Windows!) which expects "\r\n". In that case, I would send "\r\n" for that,  but only the usual "\n" for Linux. It is a not so good practice to send carriage return as well on Linux, and not just line feed even though "\r\n" may seem to work on Linux.

Comment: @Michelle: you have not mentioned some old dos before. Modern systems are fine with "\n" only. By the way, you should not send \r\n on Linux. Make sure you do a proper branching in the code and define your own endl. By the way, I updated my reply to reflect this.

Comment: The telnet client with Windows 7 has problems with just \n (it needs \r\n), but Fedora 18's telnet seems ok with \r\n at the end of each line (it seems to ignore the \r).  So I assume that there is no risk in doing so.  I read that sending endl to a stream causes a flush, so I added a flush too

Comment: @Michelle: It can cause extra characters which may confuse the other end. If you are just looking for a quick workaround, that admittedly works OK even though it is not a precise solution.

Comment: @Michelle: yes, I wrote in my comment. Have your own "endl" with platorm ifdefs surrounded.

Comment: Ifdefs only work for the compiled platform...so compiling on linux I would use \n.  But the client can be Linux or Win which is where I'm stuck.  I think I'll close the question ...not sure there is a better way